# Interior point definition

Tags: general-topology

confused on the definition on the interior point of a set in $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. The one that was introduced to us is:

$$x \in U \quad \exists \epsilon > 0 : B(x,\epsilon) \subseteq U.$$

However, for the last subseteq, why isn't it just a strict subset?
So shouldn't it read:
$$x \in U \quad\exists \epsilon > 0 : B(x,\epsilon) \subset U?$$

If I take the set $\{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^n: y=1, x \in \mathbb{R}\}$, which is the constant function $y=1$ on the cartesian plane, would I say this is a
"not-open set"?

Comment: An essence of $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ is the same. There is also $\subsetneqq$

Comment: $x$ is an interior point by the book's definition if and only if it's an interior point by your modified definition.  Maybe you can say why the book's definition feels unintuitive to you.

Comment: because it is possible that $B(x,\epsilon)=U$ for some $\epsilon$. Of course it is the same to write $B(x,\epsilon)\subsetneq U$ that $B(x,\epsilon)\subseteq U$ because $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, that is $$B(x,\epsilon)\subseteq U\implies B(x,\epsilon/2)\subsetneq U$$

Comment: Why *should* it need to be a proper subset? If $B (x\epsilon)=U $, $x $ is still an interior point. What's the confusion?

Comment: Your example, whether you mean $\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x \in \mathbb R, y = 1 \}$ or $\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^{n-1} \times \mathbb R \subset \mathbb R^n \mid x \in \mathbb R^{n-1}, y = 1 \},$ is *not* open, no matter if you take $B(x,\epsilon)$ to be a strict or non-strict subset of $U.$

Answer (score 2):

For your space, as was pointed out, it makes no difference.
In general, for other spaces, it can make a difference.
For example a T_1 space for which {x} is open.

Of course there is none in your space,
but in the space of integers there are many.

Comment: yes, this is the point IMO. I would add "topological spaces" instead of just "spaces" to be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially the same definition.

If $x\in U$ is an interior point, regarding your definition, there exist $\epsilon >0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon )\subseteq U$.

But then you can consider $\epsilon'=\epsilon /2$, and you have $B(x,\epsilon')\subset U$ (strict).

Reciprocally, if you have $\subset$, you obviously have $\subseteq$.

So the two definitions are equivalent.

And for your graph, it is indeed a non-open set, since for instance $(0,1)$ is not an interior point according to your definition.

Answer (score 1):

it does not make a difference, wether you use $ ⊆$ or ⊂ for the definition. Your example of the graph of the constant function $y=1$ (lets call it M) is not an open set, since  $ \forall x \in M \forall\epsilon >0: B_{\epsilon}(x)\nsubseteq M$

Answer (score 1):

In the case you mention ($\mathbb R^2$ equipped with usual topology) it can be proved that interchanging $\subseteq$ and $\subsetneq$ makes no difference.

See the comment of Masacroso on your question.

However the use of $B(x,\epsilon)$ indicates that you are working in metric spaces and one of them is a set $X$ equipped with metric $d$ defined by $d(x,x)=0$  and $d(x,y)=1$ if $x\neq y$ for $x,y\in X$.

In such (discrete) space every element $x\in X$ is an interior point of set $\{x\}$.

However, no $\epsilon>0$ can be found with $x\in B(x,\epsilon)\subsetneq\{x\}$.