# With the metric $(X,d) : X = \Bbb R$ and $d(x,y) = |x| + |y|$ for $x\neq y$ and $A = \{0\}$. Is interior of $A$ empty?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

With the metric space $(X,d) : X = \Bbb R$ and $d(x,y) = |x| + |y|$ for $x\neq y$, $d(x,x) = 0$ and $A = \{0\}$. Is interior of $A$ empty?

In usual metric it would be empty but with this metric I conclude that it is $A$ itself.

Def: $ a \in A $ is an interior point of $A$ if $\exists \epsilon > 0: B(a,\epsilon) \subset A$

$B(a,\epsilon) = \{x \in \Bbb R | |x| + |a| < \epsilon\} = \{0\}$

For the condition $B(a,\epsilon) \subset A$ in Def, should it be proper subset or $\{0\} \subset \{0\}$ is okay?

Comment: Please make sure to double-check your question before posting it here. You've already corrected 2 mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to substitute $a=0$, because you are trying to prove that $0$ is an interior point of $A$.

So, you need to find a positive $\varepsilon$ such that $B(0,\varepsilon) = \{x \in \Bbb R ~:~ |x|+|0|<\varepsilon\} \subseteq A$, which is obviously impossible.

Comment: Ok I see now. But then for $A = \{1\}$ it would be possible right? Int A would be  {1}

Comment: @Pumpkin yes. Intuitively, $1$ is the only point close to $1$, as other points have distance at least $1$ (actually, $d(1,0) < d(1,1.9)$, so your intuition might need to adapt to this)

Comment: I wrote the ball definition wrong x should be in X not in A

Comment: @Pumpkin right, I completely ignored and just copied it, lol

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of a $\varepsilon$ ball centred at $a$ is incorrect. With your definition every ball around every point would be a subset of $A$. The correct definition, in any metric space $(X,d)$, of a $\varepsilon$ ball centred at a point $a$ is:
$$B(a,\varepsilon)=\{x\in X:d(a,x)<\varepsilon\}.$$
In your case, for any $\varepsilon>0$, $B(0,\varepsilon)=\{x\in \mathbb R:|x|<\varepsilon\}$, which cannot be contained in $\{0\}$.

As for your last question about whether the definition should be $\subseteq$ or $\subsetneq$, I recommend looking at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2315696/interior-point-definition) post.

Comment: @KennyLau The definition the OP uses means the empty set is an $\varepsilon$ ball, which means any set has non-empty interior.

Comment: @KennyLau It wasn't like that when I made this answer, and your answer still has the same error.